# 0^0 = 1 en Oracle?

Tags: oracle-11g, matemáticas

Por qué la función power de oracle retorna un 1 en la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT POWER(0, 0) FROM dual;
```

[image]

---

Según entiendo esto debería ser una indeterminación ya que **0^0** es equivalente a decir **0^(n-n)**, suponiendo **n** un entero positivo (**n** diferente de **0** obviamente), lo cual se puede convertir en **0^n/0^n** que es igual a **0/0**, es decir, una indeterminación matemática.

Comment: Es cero. [Aquí](http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/12/q-what-does-00-zero-raised-to-the-zeroth-power-equal-why-do-mathematicians-and-high-school-teachers-disagree/) tienes una respuesta.

Comment: Correcto, puede ser 0 @A.Cedano de hecho cualquier número es solución de una indeterminación. Pero creo que Oracle debería arrojar una advertencia o error en esos casos para evitar errores silenciosos.

Comment: Tema interesante. Haciendo algo de investigación online, parece que aunque es una indeterminación, el resultado de 0^0 "debería" considerarse 1. Si entiendes inglés, hay una pregunta que lo explica en detalle en el sitio de [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)

Comment: @Juan Carlos Pico Sarmiento con ese mismo razonamiento entonces 0/0 es igual a n/n que es igual a 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hay una publicación interesante en [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1) en la que se pregunta algo parecido, ¿por qué es 0<sup>0</sup> = 1? Y en la que se pueden encontrar múltiples respuestas con explicaciones relativas al álgebra, cálculo numérico, teoría de conjuntos, matemática discreta...

Y hay una respuesta corta que puede pasar desapercibida, pero que explica por qué Oracle devuelve 1 cuando se hace `POWER(0,0)`. Es la [respuesta de kcrisman](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105102) (traducción mía):

> Me sorprende que nadie haya mencionado el [estándar IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#IEEE_floating_point_standard) para 0<sup>0</sup>. Muchos programas informáticos devolverán 0<sup>0</sup> = 1 por eso. No es una respuesta matemática en sí, pero es importante apuntarlo por el incremento de la naturaleza computacional de las matemáticas modernas, para que nadie se confunda con nada.

En la página de la Wikipedia enlazada por kcrisman, se especifica lo siguiente sobre el estándar 754 y su aplicación en los lenguajes de programación (traducción del sitio en inglés, esta parte no está disponible en la versión española del artículo):

> **Estándar IEEE para coma flotante**
>
> El estándar IEEE 754-2008 de coma flotante se usa en el diseño de la mayoría de las bibliotecas de coma flotante. Recomienda algunas funciones para calcular las potencias:
>
> - `pow` trata 0<sup>0</sup> como 1. Ésta es la versión definida más antigua. Si la potencia es un entero exacto, el resultado es el mismo que con `pown`, de lo contrario el resultado es el mismo que para `powr` (excepto en algunos casos excepcionales).
> - `pown` trata 0<sup>0</sup> como 1. La potencia debe ser un entero exacto. El valor está definido para bases negativas; p.e. `pown(-3,5)` es -243.
> - `powr` trata 0<sup>0</sup> como NaN (Not-a-Number – undefined). El valor es también NaN para casos como `powr(-3,2) en los que la base es menor que cero. El valor es definido por e<sup>power×log(base)</sup>.
>
> **Lenguajes de programación**
>
> La mayoría de los lenguajes de programación con una función de potencia (power) están implementados usando la función `pow` de IEEE y por tanto evalúan 0<sup>0</sup> como 1. Los estándares más recientes de C y C++ describen esto como el comportamiento por norma. El estándar de Java impone este comportamiento. El método `System.Math.Pow` del framework .NET también trata 0<sup>0</sup> como 1.

---

Si quieres algo más de referencia, ésta es la [página de la Wikipedia  en español sobre el estándar IEEE 754-2008](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante), y el [documento del estándar](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~tsimo1/CMSC455/IEEE-754-2008.pdf) (en inglés, en PDF).

Además, en esta página de la [documentación de Oracle para Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-), se explica cómo se calculan las potencias y los casos especiales, siendo el primer caso especial: "*si el segundo argumento es un cero positivo o negativo, el resultado es 1.0*". Si Oracle aplica el mismo criterio de cálculo para Java y para la base de datos, entonces realmente es que ni se calcula la potencia, directamente al ver el segundo argumento como 0, devuelve 1 sin pararse a comprobar cuál es el primer argumento.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @AlvaroMontoro. Muchas gracias. Muy puntual y descriptiva. No sabía que existía un estándar para la manipulación de los coma flotante.